# Rancher Desktop Kubernetes Virtualization Error

Tags: linux, kubernetes, ubuntu-18.04, rancher, rancher-desktop

I am having an issue when I try to launch Rancher Desktop. I am running Ubuntu version 18.04.6 LTS. I have a suspicion the error is because I need a newer Ubuntu version but I am not sure. Also, my CPU has virtualization enabled (checked BIOS) so I am not sure why it is doing this.

Error: virtualization does not appear to be supported on your machine

bugs: cpu_meltdown spectre_v1 spectre_v2 spec_store_bypass l1tf mds swapgs itlb_multihit srbds
bogomips: 6820.02
clflush size: 64
cache_alignment: 64
address sizes: 43 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:
2022-07-19T23:34:47.202Z: Error starting lima: Error: Virtualization does not appear to be supported on your machine.
at Qe.ensureVirtualizationSupported (/opt/rancher-desktop/resources/app.asar/dist/app/background.js:17:179719)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)

Answer (score 0):

Getting a similar error in ubuntu 20.04 rancher desktop.

```
Error: Virtualization does not appear to be supported on your machine.

bugs        : spectre_v1 spectre_v2 spec_store_bypass swapgs itlb_multihit srbds
bogomips    : 4599.93
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 39 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:
2022-07-23T14:28:30.141Z: Error starting lima: Error: Virtualization does not appear to be supported on your machine.
    at Qe.ensureVirtualizationSupported (/opt/rancher-desktop/resources/app.asar/dist/app/background.js:17:179719)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

[image]

But for me it seems like **processor is not capable of running KVM** : https://phoenixnap.com/kb/ubuntu-install-kvm

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this today. We had a power failure over the weekend and when I powered up my linux box it came up in BIOS and reset to the defaults.

On my system I found the `Advanced` menu, and had to enable the `Intel Virtualization Technology`.